# Rapidminer process failed message

Tags: text-mining, rapidminer

I use Rapidminer in text mining process 
it work with naive well but with decision tree it give error message
the dataset contains about 50000 word,I use stem and stopword filtering

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9vbp.jpg)

Comment: Can you specify how much memory is allocated for RapidMiner? Under View -> Show panel -> Ressources Monitor you can get information about the memory profile of the running RapidMiner instance.

Comment: 4.9 used. will use up to 5.8 GB